# A question regarding real valued function

Tags: functions

I have a question regarding real-valued function:

Which of the following cannot possibly be the rule of any real-valued function?

A) $y=\sqrt{x-1}$

B) $y=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt[3]{2+x}$

C) $y=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{2+x}$

D) $y=\sqrt[3]{x-1}+\sqrt{2+x}$

E) $y=\sqrt[3]{x-1}+\sqrt[3]{2+x}$

I have this feeling that if A is not a real valued function, then B and C too are not real valued functions. Since $\sqrt{x-1}$ is not much different from $\sqrt{x+2}$, then D is also not a real valued function.

Can someone assist?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there's no $\sqrt{1-x}$ or the like instead? Whether we see a real-valued function before us largely depends on the domain we want to define it on

Comment: The question being given to me is $\sqrt{x-1}$.

Comment: Each of the functions are defined for some range. What do you want to ask actually in the question?

Comment: This is what I have thought as well. Apparently, my teacher does not think so... There maybe a possibility that there are typos in the question, or I might have missed something crucial...

Comment: I think that the question is: **"Which of the following  possibly be the rule of any real-valued function?"** int this case is (E), the domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If this is the case, then the answer will make more sense. But the word "real-valued" in real-valued function only affects the range. The domain can be a subset of the reals. The range can also be a subset of reals. Then why the remaining four cannot be chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining all formulas, I got the following diagram:
[image]

With the following formulas:

> $\color{purple}{y =\sqrt{x-1}}$
>
> $\color{red}{y = \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt[3]{2+x}}$
>
> $\color{blue}{y = \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{2+x}}$
>
> $\color{green}{y = \sqrt[3]{x-1}+\sqrt{2+x}}$
>
> $\color{orange}{y = \sqrt[3]{x-1}+\sqrt[3]{2+x}}$

It shows that all formulas have real values, so the answer is none. Perhaps the question was "*Which of the following is the function of any real-valued function?*". In that case, the answer is E. While all the other function stop at a moment, the orange function doesn't have an end, and has a real value for all $x$'s